# How to check dynamically rendered checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dynamic

I'm rendering some checkboxes dynamically, but currently I'm only able to check the first box, and all other boxes operate the first one. How do I get the boxes to work independently of each other?

This is typescript in React. I've tried changing the interface I'm referencing in the function, thinking I was referencing the wrong thing, but none of those worked.

This is the function:

```
handleCheckboxClick = (entitlement: IApiEntitlements, checked: boolean): void => {
    if (checked === true) {
        this.selectedEntitlementIDs.push(entitlement.id);
    } else {
        const index: number = this.selectedEntitlementIDs.indexOf(entitlement.id);
        this.selectedEntitlementIDs.splice(index, 1);
    }
    //tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
    let entitlementChecked: IEntitlementChecked = this.state.entitlementChecked;
    entitlementChecked[entitlement.id] = checked;
    let selectAll: boolean = false;
    if (this.selectedEntitlementIDs.length === this.state.responses.apiResponses.apiClients.length) {
        selectAll = true;
    }
    this.setState({
        entitlementChecked: entitlementChecked,
        selectAll: selectAll
    });
    console.log(this.selectedEntitlementIDs, 'hi');
    console.log(entitlementChecked, 'hello');
}
```

And this is where it's being called:

```
return (
   <Checkbox
     checked={this.state.entitlementChecked[entitlement.id]}
     data-ci-key={entitlement.id}
     id='api-checkbox'
     key={entitlement.id}
     labelText={entitlement.label}
     onChange={this.handleCheckboxClick}>
   </Checkbox>
);
```

I expect each checkbox to be able to be checked, but currently on the first one works, and all others check or uncheck that first one.

Comment: Oh and for reference, `IApiEntitlements` is an interface that defines an object with an id and a label, and `IEntitlementChecked is an interface that defines an object with an id(string) that has a boolean value.

Comment: What does your state definition look like? what is the type of `entitlementChecked`?

Comment: `entitlementChecked` is set to an empty object and defined as type `IEntitlementChecked` which looks like `[id: string]: boolean`

Comment: ok so something like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-29gh1. drop the array of selected items, just use the `entitlementChecked` to keep track of checked or not.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't keep an array as a property on the class that keeps track of selected items, this isn't tied to the React lifecycle and could potentially not update the view when you want to. Instead you should just use your map (`entitlementChecked`) you already have to determine if something is checked or not.

```
handleCheckboxClick(id) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    entitlementChecked: {
      ...prevState.entitlementChecked,
      [id]: !prevState.entitlementChecked[id]
    }
  }));
}
```

When calling the handler method, you can just pass the id through that you need specifically.

```
onChange={this.handleCheckboxClick.bind(null, item.id)}
```

### [Here's a rudimentary example for more detail :)](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-29gh1)